# Printing all tables in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

### My code

```
<?php
$connessione = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
$query = mysqli_query($connessione,"SHOW TABLES");
$array=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
print_r($array,1);
?>
```

### What it should do

Printing all tables in my_db.

### What's not working

The code returns an empty page.

### What I tried to do

- I added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the page, but it doesn't return nothing;
- I run the query `SHOW TABLES` using phpMyAdmin and it works as it should.

### My question

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Erm, `$connessione = mysqli_connect ...`

Comment: Yeah, in the real code it was just like this, but it was imported through include(). While I was creating the basic sample code that I posted I forgot it. Sorry, a little distraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
<?php
    $connessione = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
    $query = mysqli_query($connessione,"SHOW TABLES");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        print_r($row);
   }
?>
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for a description of what `mysqli_fetch_array` actually does.